# change page number color of latex beamer

Tags: color, page-numbering

I need to change the page number color to black in latex beamer. What do I need to add to the following code?

```
\defbeamertemplate{headline}{page number}{%
    \vskip1pt%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]%
    \usebeamertemplate{footline}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[page number]
```

Comment: What theme are you using?  It would help if you could post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `page number` option to the `footline` template is found in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`:

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{page number}
{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
```

So when setting the footline beamer will use a font and a color `page number in head/foot`.  That color can be configured as you wish, like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{page number}{%
    \vskip1pt%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]%
    \usebeamertemplate{footline}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[page number]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=green}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Dolor sit amet}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

To learn more about these configurations, read Section 1.4, 17, and 18 of the beamer manual.

Comment: It worked .thank u...I also need to change the size of page number..what i need to add above code?

Comment: Ah, there is a configurable font as well.  Give me a minute to update.

Comment: thanx :)..what is a way to change "size of page number"?

Comment: @Emalka: see updates.  Thanks for the check but voting up is also nice. `:-)`